# Selecting using SQL Subqueries or the JOIN Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have these tables.

This table stores likes:

```
Table Name: Action

Id   Creator   Type   Target     <--- The `Target` here is the `Id` in Posts
1    1         like   1
2    2         like   1
3    3         like   1
4    1         like   2
```

This table stores posts:

```
Id   Creator
1    1
2    2
```

The column name `Creator` in any table refers to the `Id` column in the `Account` table (not shown here).

I would like to select the total number of likes that have been given to an account's posts.
I have tried the query below but it gave a syntax error.

```
SELECT count(`Id`) AS Check FROM `Action` WHERE `Type`='like' AND `Target`= (SELECT `Id` FROM `Posts` WHERE `Creator` = '1');
```

I'm not sure if a JOIN clause would be more appropriate here.

Comment: Are you able to construct a query that simply returns all the candidate rows (the results that should be counted)? If not, you may need to read about JOINs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the sums with a join of both tables and `GROUP BY` and counting the appropriate targets.

```
SELECT
    p.creator,      
    COUNT(a.target) 
FROM
    posts p
INNER JOIN
    Action a
ON
    a.target = p.id
WHERE
    a.Type = 'like' AND p.creator = 1
GROUP BY
    p.creator;
```

Comment: That works perfectly but I was asking for the total number of likes from a specific account.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL

```
    select a.ID,a.Creator,a.Type,a.Target, Count(p.*)Total
    from Action a 
    join posts p on a.Target=p.Creator
    where 
    a.Type='like'
    and a.Target=1;
```